# How can I view the source code in opencppcoverage+jenkins report

Tags: jenkins, code-coverage, cobertura

I set up code coverage environment with opencppcoverage+jenkins+cobertura, the run the code coverage for twice, but i can not view the source code in the first report

Comment: finally i set another jenkins procedure to keep the original reports